# C# Interactive as VisualStudio/ReSharper plug-in

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, metaprogramming, read-eval-print-loop

I'd like to do some "structural meta-programming" in C# (like in other languages as Smalltalk). 
 For doing so I'd like to script, using a REPL-like tool that should run "inside" VisualStudio. Doing so it would be possible to try ideas, execute refactorings programmatically, etc. from the VisualStudio itself and making use of the full meta-model capabilities it and ReSharper has. 
 I found that the tool "C# Interactive" allows to script in C# as a common REPL, but runs as a "separated process", not inside VisualStudio.
 Is there an tool like "C# Interactive" that runs as VisualStudio/ReSharper plug-in? Any hint, idea, etc. will be welcome :-)

Comment: You can load a solution into Roslyn yourself from the interactive window.

Comment: yes, but I can not access the visualstudio/resharper meta-model from there... or at least I don't know how to do it...

Comment: That's the Roslyn solution itself; what else do you want?

Comment: I'd like to remove a field programmatically for example. Or do a rename programmatically also. I can "read" the meta-model using Roslyn as REPL and using .Net reflection capabilities, but .Net reflection is only to read, not to write (get the class, get the fields, get the methods, there is no way to add a field, remove a method, etc)... therefore I'd like to use what is already done in VisualStudio and ReSharper to modify the code

Answer (score 0):

You can load Roslyn into your interactive session, then use its APIs to manipulate your code.

Create an `MSBuildWorkspace`, load your solution, then explore the Roslyn APIs to your heart's content.

No Visual Studio needed.

Comment: Hi SLaks, could you give me an example of modifying a class from Roslyn? I understand what you say, I've done that, but when I try to remove a field programmatically I do not find the way. If you could give a concrete example that would help me a lot! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may find my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension useful. The command code provides full access to the VS automation model and executes inside Visual Studio.

Comment: You may want to use https://github.com/SLaks/VSEmbed to get a better editor

Comment: @SLaks Thank you, I'm aware of your editor implementation. (Unfortunately, can't currently remember why I decided not to embed it.)

Comment: Note that embedding the editor from within VS is substantially easier.

Comment: Is it ok if the download for SSMS v2.6 is not signed?

Comment: @AlexDev Yes, SSMS 17 doesn't recognize standard vsix signature, so VisualCommanderSSMS_26.vsix is not signed.